# so many comment tags in blazor rendered html file

Tags: c#, html, .net, blazor

I was wondering if anyone knows why there are so many empty comment tags `<!--!-->` in blazor rendered HTML file
I installed 2 projects, and when I started the project I saw all of these comments 
I also downloaded a project and saw these comments in there too

[image]

Comment: How can we possibly answer this without seeing the code you are using to generate it?

Comment: it's in all of blazor projects  just install a new project and run you can see it all

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?  Even in a very large page, they will add up to maybe a few kilobytes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The comment tags are generated by the Blazor framework to help track which parts of the DOM correspond to which Blazor Components.

Comment: is there any way to remove them? 
I mean like by changing something in settings or ...

Comment: No, these are essential to how Blazor works and can’t be removed without some pretty large changes to the framework.

Comment: can you elaborate more around how, when they are created and how blazor works with them?

Comment: I believe they are created by the rendering layer of Blazor. I don't know the real detail of how they are used but they allow the render to track component boundaries in a very efficient way. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Steve Sanderson (on the Blazor team) [said](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10587#issuecomment-498180352): "The comment nodes are how Blazor tracks which part of the DOM corresponds to which Blazor components. To avoid having them, we'd need to invent and implement a totally different way of tracking this, which would be a significant block of work that could cause issues in other areas. I'm not sure we'd have any reason to do this for the forseeable future, as the comment nodes don't cause problems in known cases, or at least not mainstream ones."

Comment: One negative effect is that my co-workers that want to apply CSS styles/rules to HTML nodes have to dig through these bunch of HTML comments in the F12 developer tools live DOM tree.